# Why do Credit Card fields (and Billing fields) display before the PAYMENT METHOD is selected?

Tags: contribution-page, authorize.net

This may be specific to some payment processors. i am observing it with authorize.net.

Contribution page has 'credit card' and 'pay later' available as option, therefore the two payment methods are available as radio buttons.

When the page is opened, no Credit Card / Billing fields are displayed.

But, once an amount is selected, the Credit Card / Billing fields are displayed which results in users jumping down to fill those in, then getting an error telling them that 'payment method' needs to be chosen.

IF a default value of 'amount' is set, then the Credit Card and Billing field show immediately. Which does not seem correct to me.

UPDATE - this is an issue when using Dummy processor which ships with civi.

Comment: I've seen this too in our iATS testing - which payment processor is set to default - also plays a role; I think there may be a JIRA issue on it

Comment: Yes I concur that this relates to whether a payment processor is set to default, but i am not sure I agree if this is civi's way of saying 'credit card will always be set on the page' and therefore treats 'pay later' as the second choice. IMO 'payment method' should be able to be left with no default, and without seeing credit card fields.

Comment: Agreed - it's completely non-intuitive. It has been on my radar - but focus has been more on getting monies, transactions, financial details right - all scenarios - so I've not been able to pay to much attention to this not so great GUI experience yet.